# How to make a tab bar with images?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tabbar

I want to make an tab bar like this
[image]

I don't want to make image grey or blue on selection of a tab, which is default that when you select a tab, it will become blue, and when you unselect, it will become grey.

Comment: You need to give more information , whether this is in html or what language

Comment: this is for iOS App in swift language

Comment: please show the code if you have any so people would be more informed , and someone may help you the whole question is vague